# How to select rows with uniq value of column and to calculate count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like this for example:
I need to select each uniq column by ver and to calculate how much is total of rows by each uniq ver column
I think each total to add into the new column

```js
table:
id  name  ver 
1   one   5
2   two   5
3   three 6
4   four  6
5   five  8
```

SELECT, something like this

```js
id  ver total
1   5   2
2   6   2
4   8   1
```

Comment: `GROUP BY`, and perhaps `COUNT`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @jarlh, could you write example pleease

Comment: Sorry, you need to do it by yourself - great practice!

Comment: How `id= 2` for `ver=6` and `id=4` for `ver=8`?

Comment: Select distinct ver from table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Query**

```
select MIN(id) as id, ver, COUNT(ver) as total
from your_table_name
group by ver;
```

Comment: Why did you choose min id? look at his example of ver - 8, it got ID 4 which is not the min ID

Comment: min(id) is required because there are multiple corresponding id-s when you are using aggregate functions

Comment: Oh really? . I meant how can he know thats what he needs @istvan

Comment: By looking at the example output he gave us.

Comment: @Istvan And as I said, ver 8 got ID 4, which is not the MIN(ID).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
select min(id), ver, count(id) from table group by ver;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats a simple group by and count.. In the future please try something on your own.

```
SELECT ver,count(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY ver
```

This will give you a count for each ver, you didn't explain the logic behind the ID column, which doesn't make much sense, so I don't know what to put there.